# Check if do_action('custom_action') is hooked into?

Tags: hooks, actions

Is there a way to check if a custom hook gets called upon? I would like to display a placeholder if no output will be passed to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`has_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_action), which should ...

> Check if any action has been registered for a hook.

```
if (has_action('custom_action')) {
  // stuff
} else {
  // different stuff
}
```

Comment: Hm, okay, so this is what the question really was about... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do you know [`did_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/did_action)?

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for something like the following:

```
if (0 === did_action('custom_action')) {
    // placeholder, or whatever
}
```

Comment: Although did_action() is very useful too it works a little differently than what I was looking for in the end. If I'm correct did_action() counts the amount of time a specific do_action($) has been executed on different locations right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And that's how I understood your question. Determine if a specific action has been called (until now) and react on that data. `has_action()` returns `true` if there is at least one action registered - but it doesn't care if it's already been called or not.